# jQuery push multiple values in input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**Input tags**

```
<input id="user" type="text" name="user" class="form-control" />
<input id="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="" />
```

[image: User Autocomplete Input]

**jQuery** code to change value in hidden input when any user is searched

```
terms.push( ui.item.emp_id );
jQuery("#user_id").val(ui.item.emp_id);
```

Here `emp_id` is the userId passed from ajax response, so the input now looks like (12 is userID)

```
<input id="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="12" />
```

How can I push multiple values in input so that it look like below

```
<input id="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="12,13,14" />
```

Array being passed in `json_encode`

```
$array_pm[] = array('label' => $row['emp_name'],
                            'value' => $row['emp_name'],
                            'emp_id' => $row['emp_id']
                            );
```

My current script pushes only single value in hidden inpput, but how to push multiple values when user searches more than one record ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before you set value to input store it in some temporary variable, append the value you want to store and set the value of input to this temporary variable eg.

```
var oldValue = jQuery("#user_id").val();
var arr = oldValue === "" ? [] : oldValue.split(',');
arr.push(ui.item.emp_id);
var newValue = arr.join(',');

jQuery("#user_id").val(newValue);
```

If the `terms` is the array you want to add to input, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery("#user_id").val(terms.join(','));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9y2shao8/